# How to get checked button position in Android MaterialButtonToggleGroup

Tags: android, material-design, android-button, android-togglebutton, materialbutton

I have defined an `MaterialButtonToggleGroup` with 2 `MaterialButton` in my xml, in this way:

```xml
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButtonToggleGroup
    ...
    app:checkedButton="@+id/favorite_color1"
    app:singleSelection="true">

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/favorite_color1"
        ... />

    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/favorite_color2"
        ... />

</com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButtonToggleGroup>
```

I found `getCheckedButtonIds()` method (that returns a List of Ids) and `OnButtonCheckedListener` (that returns an Integer Id), but the `get(int index)` method returns the View at the index position, not the View with a certain id.

**How Can I get (programmatically) the View of the checked button in a given moment?**
There is a method returns the current checked position (or index)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using `app:singleSelection="true"` you can use the`getCheckedButtonId()` method to get the unique id of the selected `MaterialButton` in this group.
You can use something like:

```
MaterialButtonToggleGroup materialButtonToggleGroup = 
         findViewById(R.id.toggle_button_group);
int buttonId = materialButtonToggleGroup.getCheckedButtonId();
MaterialButton button = materialButtonToggleGroup.findViewById(buttonId);
```

You can also use `getCheckedButtonIds()` and cycle over the ids.

```
List<Integer> ids = materialButtonToggleGroup.getCheckedButtonIds();
for (Integer id:ids){
      MaterialButton materialButton = materialButtonToggleGroup.findViewById(id);
      //....
}
```

Comment: Yes, I think this is the best solution at the moment. But it seems strange that Android doesn't provide a method that returns a list of selected indexes to get the selected views with get(index) method.

Comment: @capo11 The `MaterialButtonToggleGroup` doesn't work with indexes (as an array). All the methods (`check`,`uncheck` for examples) work with the ID view.

Comment: yes, I know. There is only one method works with indexes (at the moment): `get(index: Int)`. This method is very usefull for me because of it returns a view. And I want exacly manipulate that view but I have to implement a cycle to figure out what idex belog to a selected view. I would have expected to find another method like this: `get(id: Int)` return View.

Comment: The method `get(index)` is inherited by `ViewGroup`, is not specific for the `MaterialButtonToggleGroup`